# Opening a specific MS Office program causes every executable in the desktop and below to be run simultaneously

Tags: windows-7

I'm having a strange issue with MS Visio 2016 which when I open it, either directly (i.e. double-clicking Visio's executable from the Office's folder) or by a shortcut, it runs every executable (.exe) located in the desktop folder and subfolders. This is very annoying, because there's many executables inside my desktop directory, and whenever I need to use Visio, my computer hangs because of the tons of executables opening at the same time, and then I have to terminate every one of them.

This only happens with Visio, no other program causes such strange effect, not even other Office programs. It only runs executables inside the desktop folder, no other directory outside of it. It only affects .exe files; shortcuts (.lnk) linked to an .exe are ignored. This didn't happened since I installed MS Office 2016, it started happening some weeks later. The Visio executable is in Office's directory (the default).

How can I solve this?

---

**Edit:**
As requested:

**PATH:**

C:\Program Files\Falcon\MinGW\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;
C:\Program Files\Universal Extractor\bin;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools;
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Program Files\Notepad++;
C:\Program Files\Winrar;
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox;
C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\Application\;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\;
C:\Program Files\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Ruby193\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;
%USERPROFILE%.dnx\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\;
D:\Meus Documentos\Downloads\Android\Android Development\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\;
C:\Program Files\Process Lasso\;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Roaming\npm

**"Command line" argument:**

Every program executed by Visio has the value `/visio=00380000 /launch` as the command line argument.

When Visio opens, it stops opening the executables and shows an alert that says (translating to English):

> Visio couldn't run "DirectoryMonitorConfigAssistant.exe".
>   CreateProcess returned result 740.
>   It's possible to continue running Visio.
>   Click 'OK' to continue.

Clicking OK, it continues to run the rest of the executables until there's no more to run.

"Directory Monitor" is one of the .exes located in the desktop. This was happening much before I started using Directory Monitor, but now it shows this alert, probably because Directory Monitor disallows multiple instances and is already running.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're opening Visio "directly"? What does your PATH argument look like? Using Process Explorer (from Sysinternals/Microsoft) look at the "Command Line" argument for the processes that are starting and list and add it to your question.

Comment: @music2myear Added the info you requested.